# Random "write EPIPE" error

Tags: node.js, express, request, mocha.js, chai

I'm currently making a test program for a Node.js app that is going to send HTTP requests here and there.
I'm using Chai to create my tests and Express to simulate the server.

Here's my problem : When I run the following request, everything works fine ... but if I run it multiple times, I randomly get an error.
It comes and go and doesn't seem to be linked to anything in my code, so I don't even know where to look at.

**Here's my request :**

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
let fs = require('fs');

let should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe("Test external service 'TEST'", function () {
    it('POST /testCheck', function testCheck(done) {
        chai.request('http://servicetest:8888')
            .post('/testCheck')
            .attach('files', "server.js")
            .end(function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    done();
                } else {
                    res.should.have.status(202);
                    done();
                }
            })
    })
})
```

**When it works :**

```
Test external service 'TEST'
    ✓ POST /testCheck (51ms)

1 passing (60ms)
```

**And randomly, I get this :**

```
Test external service 'TEST'
  1) POST /testCheck


0 passing (50ms)
1 failing

1) Test external service 'TEST'
     POST /testCheck:
   Error: write EPIPE
    at _errnoException (util.js:1031:13)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:873:14)
```

**Here's the code on the other side :**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/testCheck', function(req, res) {
    if ((req.get('content-type') != undefined) && (req.get('content-length') != undefined)) {
        res.status(202);
        res.end();
    } else {
        res.status(400);
        res.end();
    }
});

console.log("Server test started");
app.listen(8888);
```

I absolutely don't understand what's going on and would like to sort this out before getting to anything else.

Comment: I got the same issue. Have you found a way to fix this?

Comment: If I remember well, it had something to do with my program launching while all of the loading wasn't done yet by the other programs supposed to run beforehand, but it's been months now and I don't really know anymore

Answer (score -1):

Just follow the documentation, and it works!

https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http#setting-up-requests

```
.attach('files', fs.readFileSync('server.js'), 'server.js')
```